# Can you mix JavaScript Object Literals and Prototypes in a JS Library code structure?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript library I am building which currently uses Object Literals and I am now rebuilding it to use Prototypes instead.

Below is a part of my current app which you can see keeps several template parsing functions organized under a `templates` object...

#### Object Literal format to keep related functions organized

```
templates: {

    parse: function(template, data){

    },


    sidebarTemplate: function() {

    },

    sidebarPanelTemplate: function(panelOptionsObj) {

    },

    sidebarPanelBackButtonTemplate: function(panelOptionsObj) {

    },


    sidebarPanelLoaderTemplate: function(panelOptionsObj) {

    },
},
```

---

#### Now below is the format of my new Prototype design...

#### Prototype format

```
/**
 * Example Prototype Library Structure
 * 
 * @param  {[type]} $         [description]
 * @param  {[type]} window    [description]
 * @param  {[type]} document  [description]
 * @param  {[type]} undefined [description]
 * @return {[type]}           [description]
 */
(function($, window, document, undefined) {

    'use strict';

    var defaults = {
        fullScreen: true
    };

    var SideBar = function(element) {

        // You can access all CoreJS variables and functions like this.
        this.core = $(element).data('corejs');

        this.$el = $(element);
        this.core.s = $.extend({}, defaults, this.core.s)

        this.init();

        return this;
    }

    SideBar.prototype.init = function() {

    };

    /**
    * Destroy function must be defined.
    * CoreJS will automatically call your module destroy function 
    * before destroying the gallery
    */
    SideBar.prototype.destroy = function() {

    }

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

---

### Question

Using my new Prototype format, is there anyway to organize related functions like my template ones above for example?

Comment: You could initialize the prototype itself as an object like in your old code.

Comment: @Pointy Im not sure im following exactly how to implement could you possibly post an example?

Comment: `Sidebar.prototype = { foo: function(x, y) { ... }, bar: function() { ... } };`

Comment: @Pointy ahh yes I have seen this before it slipped my mind thanks!  Im so used to seeing prototype examples have a function value that I guess I was thinking that wasn't possibble

Comment: @Pointy if you feel like posting that as an answer I feel it best answers my issue

Answer (score 1):

### Group Related Items in an Object

It sounds like you are trying to make `namespaces` like in PHP. You can implement something similar like:

```
var Templates = {
    Sidebar: Sidebar,
    Header: Header
};

function Sidebar(width) {
    this.width = width;
}
Sidebar.prototype.setWidth = setWidth;
function setWidth(width) {
    this.width = width;
}

function Header(height) {
    this.height = height; 
}

var x = new Templates.Sidebar(3);
x.setWidth(5)
console.log(x);
```

With little effort you can wrap the components in IIFE and make them injectable without clobbering the global namespace.

There was nothing wrong with your original approach except that you were using anonymous functions, so you couldn't give them prototype methods (because you can't refer to them).